# How can I calculate and plot a plane that is perpendicular to a known vector and passes through a known point?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I want to plot the plane perpendicular to a vector, and going through a point with Matlab.
My vector has coordinates `v1 = [2,i]` and my point has coordinates `com_m1 = [1,i]`.

I have tried both:

```
xx=(-15:-6:0.25);
yy=(-10:-2:0.25);
for i = 1:length(xx)
    for j = 1:length(yy)
            zz_m1(j,i)=(v1(2,2)*(xx(i) - com1(1,1)) + v1(2,2)*(yy(j)-com1(1,2)))/v1(2,3) + com1(1,3);
    end
end
surf(xx,yy,zz_m1, 'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none') % Plotting the surface
```

and

```
[xx, yy]=meshgrid(-15:-6:0.25,-10:-1:0.25);
zz_m1=(v1(2,2)*(xx - com1(1,1)) + v1(2,2)*(yy-com1(1,2)))/v1(2,3) + com1(1,3);
surf(xx,yy,zz_m1, 'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none')
```

But both didn't work. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean didn't work? Did you get an error? If so, what was that error?

Comment: I mean I only obtain a blank plot, but no error message

Comment: @user1338219 how does your code even run? You're trying to access `v1(2, 2)`, while you defined `v1` to be `v1 = [2, i]`, which is only 1-by-2. Same comment goes for `com1`.

Comment: @ EitanT sorry maybe I explained myself wrongly: I meant v1 defined as a matrix:

[x1 y1 z1
 x2 y2 z2]

so when I access v1(2,2) I mean y2. same for com1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code. The biggest is this line, `xx=(-15:-6:0.25);` It produces an empty matrix, as your asking for a vector that starts at `-15` and continues on to `-Inf`.

If you don't understand the mistake then you should probably read the [Colon Notation Docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html)  Your matrix `yy` has the same problem as `xx`.

Additionally I think your calculations for the plane are incorrect. I tried your code locally using a randomly generated `v1` and `com1` and the line isn't normal to the plane.

Here is a nice explanation of how to compute the equation for a plane that passes through a point and is perpendicular to a known vector: http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/matlab/planes/index.xhtml (scroll down to **A Plane is a Surface**)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Indeed I was creating my matrix wrongly as I believed that the syntax was [start:stop:interval] instead of [start:interval:stop]:
Once solved that matlab polts a plane. 
I checked my equations and indeed there was a sign mistake.
Thank you very much